# App to use iMac as digital photo frame for photos on a network drive?

Tags: software-recommendation, photos, screensaver

I'd like to use a spare iMac as a ***digital photo frame*** to display my personal photos.

Desired features:

- **Turn off screen** when the room is dark (or, worst case, turn off based on a timer -- would the Energy Saver schedule be sufficient for this?)
- Access photos from a **shared network drive** (so it automatically gets new photos) -- this Mac will not actually contain a local copy of any of the pictures
- **Randomize** order of photos
- If possible, allow **multiple monitors** (with different photos on each)
- Doesn't need any fancy animation effects -- I'd prefer it being more like a static picture that doesn't change that often, just like a traditional photo on the wall

Are there any apps you'd recommend that can meet these needs (especially accessing photos from the shared network drive)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody volunteered a solution, so here's what I did...

- **Screensaver:** I used the in-built screensaver, with a few changes (see below)
- The **Default duration** of the slide show was too quick (3 seconds), so I used [OS X Mavericks screensaver changes pictures too quickly: How do I slow it down?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259173/178709) to fix it. Note the special `csrutil` instructions since Yosemite.
- **Network drive:** I mounted a network drive, then changed the **Login Options** to permanently mount it. See: [How to Automatically Connect to a Network Drive at Login in OS X](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/automatically-connect-network-drive/)
- **On/Off control:** I used the Energy Saver control panel to Wake & Sleep the machine at set times. Not as good as sensing light/motion, but it will do for now.